# Why is the empennage of some aircraft not placed on the centerline?

Tags: aerodynamics, plane-construction, dc-9-family

Check the MD80's empennage below.

[image]

Can easily tell it's not built on exactly centerline by naked eyes.

Is that because aluminum joint or consider aerodynamics?

I don't think it is manufacturing defects or imprecision.

Some of the small aircraft have the same construction like this.

Couldn't find the similar discussion online though.

Comment: Welcome to av.se :)

Comment: Very nice website, thx :)

Comment: Looking at the picture, I see that the forward portion of the empennage fairing does not line up with what appears to be a joint in the skin structure. However, the joint may be off-center compared to the rivet placement. Looking at the empennage in person may reveal it to be off centerline, but this is not clear to me from the picture. Could you further explain or document how the empennage is not on centerline?

Comment: @Jonathan Walters Good point! I don't figure out that I should compare to the rivet placement. Joint line is not centerline clearly.

Comment: This is a good question, because some aircraft *do* have off-center (or divergent or angled from the longitudinal axis) empennage. The C172 is an example of such an aircraft; I'm not sure that the DC-9/MD-80 series is.

Comment: @Jonathan Walters Off-center empennage? For better aerodynamics or compensate the other problems? Could you give me more information about this?

Comment: I haven't had my hands on a C172 in a few months, but if I remember right, the built in angle is to counteract some of the left turning tendencies and provide built in trim. The C172 doesn't have cockpit-adjustable rudder trim.

Comment: @Jonathan Walters Oh, I thought manual control the rudder to counteract that turning tendencies on a C172 is the only way. Thx, that help a lot.

Comment: @ReinFore Rudder control is the primary way, but the built in angle and the ground adjustable trim tab also provide trim.

Comment: Another possible reason is the stability of yaw control. Some plane designs had the curious (and unintended) feature that perfectly symmetrical flight was unstable in yaw, but there were two stable attitudes yawing slightly (a fraction of a degree) left and right. Early autopilots sometimes "hunted" between those two stable states while trying to maintain the unstable symmetrical state, and the side-to-side oscillations could make passengers in the rear rows of seats feel a bit airsick. Intentionally breaking the "perfect" symmetry cured the problem.

Comment: You said "aircraft", not "planes", so you should look at helicopters because almost all of them are asymmetric by definition : )

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The vertical stabilizer is on the centerline.

The line you see is not the centerline, it's the overlap of the aluminum sheets that form the circular fuselage.

[image]
([Source](http://www.airlinereporter.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Metal-to-Metal-Fuselage-Bonding.jpg))

[image]
([Source](http://www.bushburycladding.co.uk/global/fileman/Uploads/installation-screwing.png)) Non-aviation example of what I mean by overlap and centerline.

---

On the other hand, propeller aircraft may employ [different methods](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/36346/14897) to counter the [left turning tendencies](http://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/aerodynamics/4-left-turning-tendencies/).

---

> **Tail**
>
> The tail group consists of a vertical stabilizer, a horizontal stabilizer, two
>   elevators, and a rudder. The vertical stabilizer is mounted on the aft
>   fuselage, and the horizontal stabilizer is mounted on the top of the vertical
>   stabilizer. The rudder and elevators are mounted on the vertical and
>   horizontal stabilizers, respectively.
>
> The vertical stabilizer is fully cantilevered and sweptback. A scoop for
>   cooling the air-conditioning systems is located on the lower leading edge
>   section and is heated when the Airfoil Anti-ice is operating.
>
> – MD-80 Flight Manual

Back to the MD-80 in the photo, from its manual there is no mention of an offset. I searched for multiple terms such as offset, angled, and off center.

Finally, from an official CAD drawing from [Boeing's website](http://www.boeing.com/commercial/airports/3_view.page):

[image]

Comment: That make sense. Thanks very much.

Comment: @ymb1 nice editing :)

Comment: that link about left-turning tendencies is really interesting and high quality, thanks!

Comment: Awesome, thank you for your effort!

Answer (score -3):

Its my first time seeing this kind of defects. For sure its not a defect caused by manufactures. It could be that this aircraft had gone through a skin change procedures. Its the overlapping of two skins that appear to be not center or could be the dorsal fin's anchor nuts not rivets properly i guess so (refer to my experience working with b737-family).

Comment: this does not add anything to the already existing answer

Comment: Are you suggesting that this is a defect? Are you familiar with the construction of the MD-80 type? Is this, in fact, an example of defective manufacture? I have seen nothing else that suggests the photo in question depicts a defect; my understanding is that the photo shows proper construction that differs from the expectations of the OP.

Comment: I'm sure this section haven't been modified and other MD82 are the same. Have repairing experience on MD82/83.