# How to balance a propeller aircraft for left turning tendencies?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, p-factor

[image]
([Source](http://www.avsim.com/pages/1006/Saab/16.jpg)) Rudder twist on a [Saab 91 Safir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saab_91_Safir).

What are the design methods used to balance a propeller aircraft for [left turning tendencies](http://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/aerodynamics/4-left-turning-tendencies/)? I think it matters more the more powerful the engine(s) is.

A rudder twist seems to be one, not-so-detailed [sources](http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=256155) mention an offset engine, a slightly longer-, or differently balanced wing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways, and the most effective vary their own yawing moment contribution with engine thrust:

- A trim tab on the rudder which forces it into a correcting deflection. This trim tab can either be adjusted in flight or only on the ground. The flight-adjustable trim tab is set according to flight speed and is used on airplanes with a wide speed range.
- Mounting the engine at a slight angle to the airplane centerline. This places the propeller at an offset which produces its own yawing moment.
- Camber on the vertical tail. Since the tail is in the propeller slipstream, it experiences a relatively higher dynamic pressure at low speed and high engine settings, just when the [p-factor](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/312/whats-p-factor-and-why-does-it-occur) is biggest.

Answer (score 1):

Rudder twist seems like an exotic and expensive means to solve the problem.  Most light aircraft use a pre-set rudder trim tab set during flight test at the factory, like this on a CE-172.

[image]([boldmethod](http://www.boldmethod.com/learn-to-fly/systems/4-types-of-trim-tabs))

Comment: Set at the factory and adjusted by the operator according to need.